# Max int and range values confusiion

Tags: types, programming-languages

I got slightly confused and I on the web I can only see a half of the answer.
It is said that UInt16 has the range of values 0-65335. Also the **total** number of values in16 can hold is 2^16 (65336), the same for 2^32 etc.
If it is signed, it is still 2^16. The min and max being 32768 - +32767. I guess 32768-1 is because of the 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of *two's complement* notation, which is commonly used to encode negative numbers. Let's take 8-bit integers as an example to save me some typing.

Unsigned numbers are encoded as follows:

```
   0  00000000
   1  00000001
   2  00000010
 ...  ........
 254  11111110
 255  11111111
```

For signed integers, zero and the positive values have the same notation as in the unsigned case:

```
   0  00000000
   1  00000001
   2  00000010
 ...  ........
 126  01111110
 127  01111111
```

But now something interesting happens. For the next larger value, 11111111, we wrap around to negative, and continue counting upwards:

-128  10000000
-127  10000001
-126  10000010
....  ........
  -2  11111110
  -1  11111111

As you can see, there are 128 possible negative numbers, and 128 possible positive/zero numbers. Because zero is included among the positive numbers, only 127 slots remain for strictly positive integers.

You might wonder why we don't consider 10000000 as 128, and wrap around at the next value, treating 10000001 as -127. I think this is because it breaks the nice pattern: negative numbers start with a 1 in their most significant bit, nonnegative numbers start with a 0. It is also nicer for symmetry with unsigned numbers, where the maximum positive value is also 2<sup>*n*</sup> - 1, not 2<sup>n</sup>.

Comment: Thank you, is that correct that int16 in total stores 2^16 values, as I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, it is, regardless of signed or unsigned. There are 16 bits, each bit can have 2 values, hence 2^16 values.